# How to define data type of a property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

According to [neo4j-datatypes](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html) properties have primitive data types.

1. How can I define the data type when I create properties. For exmple in following query, how can I define the property "age" as a "short" data-type explicitly?

   ```
   MATCH (e:Employee) SET e.age = 55
   ```
2. What is the default data type of age as per above query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Cypher supports the following [basic types](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/cypher-values/#driver-basic-types): `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Float`, `String`, `List` and `Map`.

When working with Cypher, you do not define the data type. The data type that best fits your value will be chosen for you.

In the indicated query, `e.age` will be always an `Integer`. If you change the value for one that don't fits `Integer` values, then the type will be changed. For example: `MATCH (e:Employee) SET e.age = 55.5` will change the data type for `Float`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, I know, and the answer may have been correct at the time given, but I will nevertheless refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524709/48779.

It is possible to use cypher functions when importing which means that you can use functions like `toInt`, `date`, etc.

Also note that according to https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/values/ the type landscape of Neo4j has broadened considerably making types like *Date*, *Time*, *LocalTime*, *DateTime*, *LocalDateTime* and *Duration* available.

Unfortunately still no guid/uuid, though ;)